# Filtragem client side de um DataSource

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estou desenvolvendo uma consulta de uma massa de dados do meu servidor, com o propósito de alimentar um DataTable (no caso, o do Angular Material). Estou utilizando o CollectionViewer e DataSource da biblioteca CDK.

Na resposta que eu recebo da API contém dois campos que eu preciso utilizar para filtragem, sendo os campos "Cancelado" e "Assinado". Minha necessidade é conseguir exibir Assinado ou Não assinado caso o item atenda a uma das duas condições, ou exibir Cancelado caso tenha sido cancelado, independente se foi assinado ou não.

Consegui fazer a parte da exibição utilizando o código a seguir:

```
const arrayItens: ItensDto[] = response['content'];
    for (const item of arrayItens) {
      if (item.cancelado) {
        item.status = 'Cancelado';
      } else if (item.assinado) {
        item.status = 'Assinado';
      } else {
        item.status = 'Não assinado';
      }
    }

<ng-container matColumnDef="status">
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</mat-header-cell>
<mat-cell class="statusCell" *matCellDef="let item">
    <mat-chip-list>
        <mat-chip *ngIf="item.status === 'Cancelado'">Cancelado</mat-chip>
        <mat-chip *ngIf="item.status === 'Não assinado'" selected color="warn">Não assinado</mat-chip>
        <mat-chip *ngIf="item.status === 'Assinado'" selected>Assinado</mat-chip>
    </mat-chip-list>
</mat-cell>
```

Para propósito de exibição, consigo diferenciar entre as condições muito bem no datatable, mas meu objetivo principal é conseguir filtrar esses dados no client side, já que o campo "status" não existe na resposta.

Estou aberto a sugestões também, sobre formas melhores de atingir o que eu preciso.

Comment: cara da uma olhada na função de array map e filter.

Comment: o for quase nunca é utilizado em js